# Branching a recursive function using OpenMP at top level

Tags: c, recursion, parallel-processing, openmp

Context:

Suppose I have a function `f` with a non-fixed branching factor `b`. The execution starts at a depth of 0, and stops at a given, fixed depth. I want to parallelize the execution of `f` such that, when the depth is 0, each branch of depth 1 *and its entire execution at depths greater than 1* will go and execute onto a distinct thread (onto the same thread).

I'm using OpenMP to achieve this, but I'm having trouble undestanding the effects of pragmas on recursive code (more precisely variables in the code). Basically, my problem is reduced to the following code (which does not behave correctly):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "omp.h"


int b = 6;
int maxDepth = 4;

void f(int depth) {
    if (depth == maxDepth)
        return;
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < depth; i++) printf("   ");
    }
    printf("D %d TID %d\n", depth, omp_get_thread_num());
    if (!depth) {
        int i;
        #pragma omp parallel for private(i)
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            f(depth+1);
        }
    }
    else {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
            f(depth+1);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    f(0);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

With regards to the code above, how should I set the privacy (`shared`, `private`) of the variables using pragmas, to what variables should I apply this, *and why*?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you look at OpenMP tasks for recursive probllems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `#pragma omp for` directive, try using tasks.
On the most recent OpenMP standards there is a new loop directive that is used for task creation: `#pragma omp taskloop`.

Another way of achieving the same goal is to split your function `f()` in two:

```
void f(int depth) {
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel private(i)
    {
      //#pragma omp for or ...
      #pragma omp single
      #pragma omp taskloop
      for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        f_nontopmost(depth+1);
      }
      // taskloop will implicitly wait for all created tasks
      // at the end
    }
}

void f_nontopmost(int depth) {
    if (depth == maxDepth)
        return;

    int i;
    // since we are in parallel section, we can still create tasks
    #pragma omp taskloop
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        f(depth+1);
    }
}
```